# Como nomear variáveis e organizá-las no código no que vai além da PEP 8?

Tags: python, convenções-de-nome, convenções

Onde eu poderia encontrar dicas pra nomear variáveis, pra organizar o código, etc.?

Por exemplo, tenho uma classe e ela tem vários atributos, alguns dependem que um outro atributo tenha sido declarado antes, mas outros são independentes, como poderia ordenar qual colocar primeiro e depois? Exemplo:

```
class Button(object):
    defs __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.draw = True
        self.moved = False
        self.text = font.render(text, True, color)
        ...
```

Nunca li nada que dissesse como por em ordem os atributos, ordem alfabética talvez? E outra coisa tentei usar todos os nomes em inglês mas acabei esbarrando em alguns que eu nao consegui traduzir por exemplo vazas, truco...

Onde eu posso encontrar coisas assim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia começar [chamando de campos em vez de atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101), afinal a linguagem oficialmente chama [outra coisa de atributo](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/).

Não há regra sobre a ordem dos campos, em geral deveriam ser colocados em ordem que faça sentido, que ajude ler o código mais facilmente, por isso os que são dependências de outros deveria vir antes. Deveria ter um certo agrupamento, e considerar a importância deles. Só com o requisito dá para saber como fazer. Ordem alfabética costuma ser terrível e pode denotar outro problema.

Note que aí são variáveis usadas localmente. Particularmente não gosto dessa forma de inicialização, mas é coisa minha. E assim a dependência precisa ser respeitada.

Se tem dificuldade com o inglês, não o use. Melhor fazer em português do que fazer algo ruim em inglês. Nem em português eu sei do que está falando. Você pode procurar palavras em inglês no dicionário. Mas ele não ajudam muito porque não é o termo usado efetivamente em grande parte dos casos. Os nomes devem ser dados para expressar bem o que eles realmente são. Se o domínio que está solucionando é em português, faça em português. Se o domínio é em inglês e não sabe quais são os termos é o caso de pedir ajuda para outra pessoa que saiba, não só para traduzir.

Entender profundamente o problema e como resolvê-lo é muito mais importante, e feito isso a solução vem naturalmente. Não feito, nada salvará o código.

Note que a pergunta não tem nada a ver com Python, nomenclatura ou convenções em si. Tem alguma coisa estilo de codificação e com algo que não é programação.